# Simple pair matching algorithm with binary preferences

Tags: algorithm, matching

I'm looking for a pair matching algorithm for a really simple problem:

- People self-assign into categories A or B or both A and B.
- They express preferences: to be matched with people in categories A, B, or either.
- Everyone is paired up (unless an odd number). Score 2 points if both people's preferences have been met, 1 if 1 person's preferences are met, 0 otherwise.

I want to find an algorithm that produces the optimal result possible for any given set of people.

Additional requirement: the chance of a person ending up unpaired must never be reduced by adding an additional category or preference. (It's ok if removing a category or preference harms their chances, however.)

There are algorithms for more complex scenarios like the Stable Marriage Problem, but my situation seems pretty simple - I'm just not sure how to go about it. The total number of people will be in the 20-50 range, so inefficient solutions are fine.

#### Example:

"1. A -> A,B" means person 1 is in category A and wants to match someone in either A or B.

Let's say we have these people:

1. A -> A,B
2. A -> B
3. A -> B
4. A -> A
5. B -> A
6. B -> A

I think we can see by inspection that an optimum solution is 1+4, 2+5, 3+6.

#### Cost function

In case the text description above wasn't sufficiently formal, the scoring I mean:

- A->A + A->A, B->B + B->B, A->B + B->A: 2 points
- A->A + B->A, A->B + B->B, A->B + A->A, B->A + B->B: 1 point
- A->A + B->B, A->B + A->B, B->A + B->A: 0 points

Comment: Can you describe it more formally? E.g. a real cost-function formula? Maybe a small example. (hunch: NP-hard)

Comment: See my edits.  ..

Comment: I guess the complexity is not related to the number of people, but to the number of types of people, of which there are 9: Aa, Ab, Aab, Ba, Bb, Bab, ABa, ABb, ABab (where Xy is an X who prefers a Y). This would reduce the input to 9 counts. And only (Aa,Bb), (Ab,Ab) and (Ba,Ba) are complete mismatches, so you'd start with pairing Aa, Bb, Ab and Ba's first. In general, an Xy is harder to match than an Xxy or XYx, and the easiest is an XYxy, so you'd try to match them in that order. (I haven't figured out whether Xxy or XYx should come first.)

Comment: Given the numbers pure exhaustive-search seems to be slightly to complex. In this case i recommend a basic problem-exploiting branch-and-bound search.

Comment: One (unstated) issue I have with matching in that order is it means people with more specific preferences are less likely to end up unpartnered, perhaps. (Imagine 3 people: Ab, Ba, ABab - the third person would always miss out.). I think I should add a requirement "the chance of a person ending up unpaired must never be reduced by adding an additional category or preference".

Comment: That would only be a problem with an uneven number, of course. An ABab would be a match with anyone else. If you regard 2+0 as an equally good score as 1+1, then I think it can be proven that pairing all the Aa, Bb, Ab and Ba's first cannot be improved upon. That would leave you with at most one Aa, at most one Bb, and either no Ab's or no Ba's.

Answer (score 1):

Its a kind of inefficient solution but i think it works. First i use a class person which has 3 private attitudes id, category and preference.

```
public class Person {
private String category;
private String pref;
private int id;

/**
 * The strings a,b will be A for A, B for B and A,B for Both 
 * @param a expressing the category that they want to go
 * @param b expressing the preference
 */
Person(int id,String a,String b){
    this.id=id;
    category=a;
    pref=b;
}

public String getCategory(){
    return category;
}

public String getPref(){
    return pref;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}
```

}

In the main class i take data from a txt file named a.txt and the format of each person has to be A -> B like the one you gave. It runs 3 private methods to get first the matches that give 2 points, then the mathces that give 1 point and then fill the rest.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pairing {
private ArrayList<Person> queue;
private ArrayList<String> matches;
private int ids;

public Pairing() {
    queue = new ArrayList<>();
    ids = 0;

}

public void addPerson(String category, String preference) {
    queue.add(new Person(ids, category, preference));
    ids++;

}

public ArrayList<String> getMatches() {
    matches = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(ids);
    checkFor2Points();
    checkFor1Point();
    //matchTheRest();
    return matches;
}

/**
 * At the begin matches the persons who has strict preferences and belongs
 * in the first 2 categories, then uses the flexibility that A,B category
 * provides to find the rest matches that will give 2 points.
 */
private void checkFor2Points() {
    Person c, p;
    for (int j = 0; j < queue.size(); j++) {
        p = queue.get(j);
        System.out.println(p.getCategory() + " " + p.getPref());
        if ((p.getCategory().equals("A") || p.getCategory().equals("B")) && (p.getPref().equals("A") || p.getPref().equals("B"))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
                c = queue.get(i);
                if (c.getPref().equals(p.getCategory()) && c.getCategory().equals(p.getPref()) && c.getId() != p.getId()) {
                    matches.add(p.getId() + 1 + "+" + (c.getId() + 1));
                    queue.remove(c);
                    queue.remove(p);
                } else if (c.getCategory().equals("A,B") && c.getPref().equals(p.getCategory()) && c.getId() != p.getId()) {
                    matches.add(p.getId() + 1 + "+" + (c.getId() + 1));
                    queue.remove(c);
                    queue.remove(p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < queue.size(); j++) {
        p = queue.get(j);
        if (p.getPref().equals("A,B")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
                c = queue.get(i);
                if (c.getPref().equals(p.getCategory()) && c.getId() != p.getId()) {
                    matches.add(p.getId() + 1 + "+" + (c.getId() + 1));
                    queue.remove(c);
                    queue.remove(p);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

private void checkFor1Point() {
    Person c, p;
    for (int j = 0; j < queue.size(); j++) {
        p = queue.get(j);
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
            c = queue.get(i);
            if ((p.getCategory().equals(c.getPref()) || p.getPref().equals(c.getCategory())) && p.getId() != c.getId()) {
                matches.add(p.getId() + 1 + "+" + (c.getId() + 1));
                queue.remove(c);
                queue.remove(p);
            }
        }
    }

}

private void matchTheRest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i += 2) {
        matches.add(queue.get(i).getId() + "+" + queue.get(i + 1).getId());
        queue.remove(queue.get(i));
        queue.remove(queue.get(i + 1));
        if (queue.size() == 1) {// that means that the ids is an odd number
            return;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String getLineString;
    String toSplit[];
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a.txt"));
    Pairing pair = new Pairing();
    getLineString = in.readLine();
    while (getLineString != null) {
        toSplit = getLineString.split(" -> ");
        pair.addPerson(toSplit[0], toSplit[1]);
        getLineString = in.readLine();
    }
    ArrayList<String> pairs = pair.getMatches();
    for (int i = 0; i < pairs.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(pairs.get(i));
    }

}
```

}